# OAuth client credential flow and sessions

Tags: oauth, session-management

When a web server uses client credentials grant to perform OAuth and access APIs in a backend service, should it create one token for every user login to the web server ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "every user login to the web server". Do you mean each time a user authenticates to the provider or for each separate user?